# How to dynamically add table data and rows to html table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 2 rows and 8 td elements. The goal is to add rows and td elements to the existing table based on data from the server. Lets say there are 12 elements from the server I have fetched so I must add 1 row and 4 td elements to the existing table of 8 td elements and 2 rows. Each row can only have 4 td elements. The current code I have works good until I reach 25 elements from the server and everything breaks. Below is code that determines how many rows to add and proceeds to td to those rows based on the data provided. I have used a recursive function but I feel that my logic is very wrong here...

```
function addEls(data, rows, remainder, num_count){
console.log('I am called...');
var control = rows.length;
console.log('Remainder: ' + remainder);
console.log('Rows to add bro: ' + control);
console.log('Count bro: ' + num_count);
if(num_count < control && rows.length > 1 && remainder !== 0){
  console.log('Am I used as well...');
  for(var items = 0; items < 4; items ++){
    //console.log('Count in row: ' + element + control);
    var element = rows[num_count].id;
    console.log('Row in use: ' + element);
    console.log('Count in row: ' + num_count);
    var str_name = String('#' + element);
    jQuery("<td><a><img class='bubbleImgMedia' id='"+items+"' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/concert.jpg'  width='172' height='172' /></a>").appendTo(str_name);
    media_list.push(document.getElementById(items));

  }
  num_count += 1 ;
  console.log('Count check: ' + num_count);
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
  rows.pop();
  console.log('Row order: ' + rows[0].id);
  if(num_count <= control){
    console.log('Recurring...');
    console.log('Count check 2: ' + num_count);
    return addEls(data, rows, remainder, num_count);
  }
}
else if(num_count <= control && rows.length === 1 && remainder !== 0){
  console.log('Am I ever used...');
  for(var items = 0; items < remainder; items ++){
    console.log('Well then...');
    var element = rows[0].id;
    console.log('Row in use: ' + element);
    var str_name = String('#' + element);
    jQuery("<td><a><img class='bubbleImgMedia' id='"+items+"' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/concert.jpg'  width='172' height='172' /></a>").appendTo(str_name);
    media_list.push(document.getElementById(items));
  }
  num_count += 1 ;
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
  rows.pop();
  console.log('Row order: ' + rows[0].id);
  if(count <= control){
    return addEls(data, rows, remainder, num_count);
  }
}
else if(remainder === 0 && rows.length === 1 && data['media'] === 12){
  console.log('This is happening...');
  for(var items = 0; items < 4; items ++){
    console.log('Well then...');
    var element = rows[0].id;
    console.log('Row in use: ' + element);
    var str_name = String('#' + element);
    jQuery("<td><a><img class='bubbleImgMedia' id='"+items+"' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/concert.jpg'  width='172' height='172' /></a>").appendTo(str_name);
    media_list.push(document.getElementById(items));
    console.log('Media list count: ' + media_list.length);
  }
  num_count += 1 ;
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
  rows.pop();
  console.log('Row order: ' + rows[0].id);
}
else if(remainder === 0 && rows.length >= 1 && num_count <= rows.length){
  //console.log('This is happening...');
  for(var items = 0; items < 4; items ++){
    console.log('Well then...hmm');
    var element = rows[0].id;
    console.log('Row in use: ' + element);
    var str_name = String('#' + element);
    jQuery("<td><a><img class='bubbleImgMedia' id='"+items+"' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/concert.jpg'  width='172' height='172' /></a>").appendTo(str_name);
    media_list.push(document.getElementById(items));
    console.log('Media list count: ' + media_list.length);
    console.log('Num count check: ' + num_count);
  }
  num_count += 1 ;
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
  rows.pop();
  //console.log('Row order: ' + rows[0].id);
  if(count <= control){
    return addEls(data, rows, remainder, num_count);
  }
}
else if(remainder >= 1 && rows.length === 1){
  console.log('Turn of events...' + rows[0].id);
  for(var items = 0; items < remainder; items ++){
    var list = [...document.getElementsByClassName('addRow')].length
    var list2 = [...document.getElementsByClassName('addRow')][list - 1]
    var element = list2.id;
    console.log('Well then...hmm');
    console.log('Row in use: ' + element);
    var str_name = String('#' + element);
    jQuery("<td><a><img class='bubbleImgMedia' id='"+items+"' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/concert.jpg'  width='172' height='172' /></a>").appendTo(str_name);
    media_list.push(document.getElementById(items));
    console.log('Media list count: ' + media_list.length);
  }
  num_count += 1 ;
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
  rows.pop();
  //console.log('Row order: ' + rows[0].id);
}
else if(rows.length > 1 && remainder !== 0 ){
  //console.log('This is happening...');
  for(var items = 0; items < 4; items ++){
    console.log('Magic city boy...');
    var element = rows[0].id;
    console.log('Row in use: ' + element);
    var str_name = String('#' + element);
    jQuery("<td><a><img class='bubbleImgMedia' id='"+items+"' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/concert.jpg'  width='172' height='172' /></a>").appendTo(str_name);
    media_list.push(document.getElementById(items));
    console.log('Media list count: ' + media_list.length);
  }
  num_count += 1 ;
  rows.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b});
  rows.pop();
  //console.log('Row order: ' + rows[0].id);
  if(count <= control){
    return addEls(data, rows, remainder, num_count);
  }
}
else{
  console.log('This is it... 4');
  console.log('Rows left : ' + rows);
  console.log('Remainder: ' + remainder);
  console.log('Count After: ' + num_count);
    }
}

$('document').ready(function(){
var e_pk = event_pk;
var interval = 12;
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url: '/ajax/get_media_info/',
  data: { 'event_pk': e_pk, 'interval':interval },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    var rows_toAdd = [];
    media = data['media']
    media_count = 0;
    row_count = 2;
    //console.log('Ajax Media List: ' + data['media']);
    media.forEach(el => {
      media_count +=1;
    });
    if(data['media'].length > 8 && media_count % 2 === 0 && media_count % 4 === 0 && data['media'].length <= 12 ){
            console.log('Option 1');
            row_count += 1;
            var num = data['media'].length - 8;
            add_row = num / 4;
            var num2;
            var rows_toAdd = [];
            console.log('Rows to add look: ' + add_row);
            console.log('Maths: ' + 11 % 4);
            console.log('Maths 2: ' + 11 / 4)
            var remain = data['media'].length % 4;
            if(add_row % 1 !== 0){
              console.log('Number is decimal');
              add_row += 1;
              console.log('Rows: '+ add_row);
              for(var control =1; control < add_row; control++){
                var name = String('row'+control);
                jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                console.log('Rows list: ' + rows_toAdd.length);
                console.log('Smoking Gun: ' + data['media'].length);
              }
            }
            else{
              for(var control =0; control < add_row; control++){
                var name = String('row'+control);
                jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                console.log('Smoking Gun: ' + media_count);
              }
            }
            console.log('Test: ' + rows_toAdd);
            addEls(data, rows_toAdd, remain, 0);
          }
          else if(data['media'].length > 8 && media_count % 2 === 0 && media_count % 4 === 0 && data['media'].length >= 12 ){
            console.log('Option 1.1');
            row_count += 1;
            var num = data['media'].length - 8;
            add_row = num / 4;
            var num2;
            var rows_toAdd = [];
            console.log('Rows to add look: ' + add_row);
            console.log('Maths: ' + 11 % 4);
            console.log('Maths 2: ' + 11 / 4)
            var remain = data['media'].length % 4;
            if(add_row % 1 !== 0){
              console.log('Number is decimal');
              add_row += 1;
              console.log('Rows: '+ add_row);
              for(var control =1; control < add_row; control++){
                var name = String('row'+control);
                jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                console.log('Rows list: ' + rows_toAdd.length);
                console.log('Smoking Gun: ' + data['media'].length);
              }
            }
            else{
              for(var control =0; control < add_row; control++){
                var name = String('row'+control);
                jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                console.log('Smoking Gun: ' + media_count);
              }
            }
            console.log('Test: ' + rows_toAdd);
            addEls(data, rows_toAdd, remain, 0);
          }
          else if(data['media'].length > 8 && media_count % 2 === 0 && media_count % 4 !== 0 && data['media'].length <= 12 ){
            row_count += 1;
            var num = data['media'].length - 8;
            add_row = num / 4;
            var num2;
            var rows_toAdd = [];
            console.log('Rows to add look: ' + add_row);
            console.log('Maths: ' + 11 % 4);
            console.log('Maths 2: ' + 11 / 4)
            var remain = data['media'].length % 4;
            if(add_row % 1 !== 0){
              console.log('Number is decimal');
              add_row += 1;
              console.log('Rows: '+ add_row);
              for(var control =1; control < add_row; control++){
                var name = String('row'+control);
                jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                console.log('Smoking Gun 1: ' + media_count);
                console.log('Rows list: ' + rows_toAdd.length);
              }
            }
            else{
              for(var control =0; control < add_row; control++){
                var name = String('row'+control);
                jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                console.log('Smoking Gun 1: ' + media_count);
                console.log('Rows list: ' + rows_toAdd.length);
              }
            }
            addEls(data, rows_toAdd, remain, 0);
            }
            else if(data['media'].length > 8 && media_count % 2 !== 0 && media_count % 4 !== 0 && data['media'].length <= 12 ){
              row_count += 1;
              var num = data['media'].length - 8;
              add_row = num / 4;
              var num2;
              var rows_toAdd = [];
              console.log('Rows to add look: ' + add_row);
              console.log('Maths: ' + 11 % 4);
              console.log('Maths 2: ' + 11 / 4)
              var remain = data['media'].length % 4;
              if(add_row % 1 !== 0){
                console.log('Number is decimal');
                add_row += 1;
                console.log('Rows: '+ add_row);
                for(var control =1; control < add_row; control++){
                  var name = String('row'+control);
                  jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                  rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                  console.log('Smoking Gun 1: ' + media_count);
                  console.log('Rows list: ' + rows_toAdd.length);
                }
              }
              else{
                for(var control =0; control < add_row; control++){
                  var name = String('row'+control);
                  jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                  rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                  console.log('Smoking Gun 1: ' + media_count);
                  console.log('Rows list: ' + rows_toAdd.length);
                }
              }
              addEls(data, rows_toAdd, remain, 0);
            }
            else if(data['media'].length > 8 && media_count % 2 !== 0 && media_count % 4 !== 0 && data['media'].length >= 12){
              //count_add = data['concerts'].length - 8;
              console.log('Option 3');
              row_count += 1;
              var num = data['media'].length - 8;
              add_row = num / 4;
              var num2;
              var rows_toAdd = [];
              console.log('Rows to add: ' + add_row);
              console.log('Maths: ' + 11 % 4);
              console.log('Maths 2: ' + 11 / 4)
              var remain = data['media'].length % 4;
              if(add_row % 1 !== 0){
                console.log('Number is decimal');
                add_row += 1;
                console.log('Rows: '+ add_row);
                for(var control =1; control < add_row; control++){
                  var name = String('row'+control);
                  jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                  rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                  console.log('Smoking Gun 1: ' + media_count);
                }
              }
              console.log('Test: ' + rows_toAdd);
              addEls(data, rows_toAdd, remain, 0);

            }
            else if(data['media'].length > 8 && media_count % 2 === 0 && media_count % 4 !== 0 && data['media'].length >= 12){
              //count_add = data['concerts'].length - 8;
              console.log('Option 4');
              row_count += 1;
              var num = data['media'].length - 8;
              add_row = num / 4;
              var num2;
              var rows_toAdd = [];
              console.log('Rows to add: ' + add_row);
              console.log('Maths: ' + 11 % 4);
              console.log('Maths 2: ' + 11 / 4)
              var remain = data['media'].length % 4;
              if(add_row % 1 !== 0){
                console.log('Number is decimal');
                add_row += 1;
                console.log('Rows: '+ add_row);
                for(var control =1; control < add_row; control++){
                  var name = String('row'+control);
                  jQuery("<tr class='addRow' id='" + name + "'></tr>").appendTo('.thead-inverse');
                  rows_toAdd.push(document.getElementById(name));
                  console.log('Smoking Gun 1: ' + media_count);
                  }
                }
                addEls(data, rows_toAdd, remain, 0);
              }
          else{
          console.log('None of the conditions met');
          console.log('Count Media : ' + data['media'].length);
          }
        },
        error:function(data){

        }
      });
});

<table class="table" id="mediaTable">
  <thead class='thead-inverse' >
  <tr>
    <td>

      <p>{{ concert.image }}</p>
      <img class="bubbleImgMedia" id='imgMedia' src="" width="150" height="150" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image" name='' label='' />
      <p class="bubbleInfo">{{ concert.number }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>

      <p>{{ social.image }}</p>
      <img class="bubbleImgMedia" id='imgMedia' src="" width="150" height="150" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image" name='' label='' />

    </td>
    <td>

      <p>{{ music.image }}</p>
      <img class="bubbleImgMedia" id='imgMedia' src="{% static 'img/coachella/image3.jpg' %}"  data-lightbox="image-3" width="150" height="150" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image" name='' />
    </td>
    <td>

      <p>{{ market.image }}</p>
      <a class="bubbleImgAnchor" href=""></a>
      <img id='imgMedia' class="bubbleImgMedia" src="{% static 'img/coachella/image4.jpg' %}" data-lightbox="image4.jpg"  width="150" height="150" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image" name=''/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <p>{{ concert.image }}</p>
      <img id='imgMedia' class="bubbleImgMedia" src="{% static 'img/coachella/image5.jpg' %}"  width="150" height="150" name='' label='' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image"/>
      <p class="bubbleInfo">{{ concert.number }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>

      <p>{{ social.image }}</p>
      <img id='imgMedia' class="bubbleImgMedia" src={% static 'img/coachella/image6.jpg' %} width="150" height="150" name='' label='' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image"/>
    </td>
    <td>

      <p>{{ music.image }}</p>
      <img id='imgMedia' class="bubbleImgMedia" src={% static 'img/coachella/image7.jpg' %} width="150" height="150" name='' label='' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image"/>
    </td>
    <td>

      <p>{{ market.image }}</p>
      <img id='imgMedia' class="bubbleImgMedia" src={% static 'img/coachella/image8.jpg' %} width="150" height="150" name='' label='' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-image"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If this is minimal then there could be a long wait.

Comment: dude, this too much, no one is going to read this whole code, please make it smaller to see the code of what you are trying

Comment: Sorry guys I will edit the code, i thought it would be clearer if I showed that much :/

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well in general for appending table data:

```
function appendTableData(table, data) {
    for (let element of data) {
      let row = table.insertRow();
      for (key in element) {
        let cell = row.insertCell();
        let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
        cell.appendChild(text);
      }
    }
  }
```

Where `table` is the target and `data` is the appended data.